# Adding new asset folder to rails asset pipeline

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have been reading this tutorial on rails asset pipeline. 
http://coderberry.me/blog/2012/04/24/asset-pipeline-for-dummies/

I added this line to my application.rb

```
  config.assets.paths << "#{Rails.root}/other/assets"
```

When I add my path

```
image-path("rails.png")
```

It's not showing my rails.png The rails.png file is inside my folder other > assets
anyone know why it might not be showing.

Comment: Where exactly are you using `image-path`? In a view or in a Sass file?

Comment: and there is an `image` path in `other/assets/` and rails.png is in there?

Comment: yes the image rails.jpg is in the folder assets which is inside the folder other.